# Azure Data Catalog Questions

Tags: azure, azure-data-catalog

I have some couple of questions related to Azure Data Catalog.

1. Is it possible to do metadata refresh without re-registering the source again?
2. Is it possible to model row level and column level security of data sources using API feature in Data Catalog?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, this should work.
2. You can put in your own custom content but not your own fields. So you would have to re-use an existing field like description to encode this information.